How was division taught in the 70's and 80's?
I was reading an article about education in the 80's and the way divisions were taught in school was really difficult for me that I have a certain degree of education. For example, 9/3, could be represented as:
  _____ 
3/  9

And you were doing the maths and get 3.
Then I realize that if you use decimals in here it comes with more complexity and for a kid it should be why they hated maths so badly, i.e. 7/1.5.
    _____
1.5/  7  

My question why it was taught that way if you could get a quicker solution using fractions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is probably more appropriate for https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Even if the site is an English speaking one, contributors can live in various countries. Are you interested in how division was taught in school anywhere on earth?

In the late 1960s where I went to school, we simply moved the decimal point in each number the same number of places sufficient to eliminate decimals. So to divide 1.5 into 7 we'd just divide 15 into 70. Surely this is still taught in grade school?

I am surprized that you consider as equivalent 1) a pure "static" rational number $7/1.5$ or $14/3$  and 2) the fact of performing (long) division of $7$ by $1.5$ which is an algorithm giving a decimal representation.

Can you explain how you can get $1.5/7 \approx .2142857$ using fractions?

You don't get the answer any "quicker" writing the division problem as a fraction.  The division symbol you used is extremely useful for hand division, which might lead to a large number of digits.

I was a school pupil en France in the 60's and 70's. We were first taught integer numbers and learned how to count them first till 10 then till 100 etc.
Next we learned addition and substraction (only with positive numbers: $4-5$ was declared impossible because if John has 4 marbles, he cannot give 5 to Peter...).
After that we learned multiplication (still only integers). And only after that all, we went to division. And we learned the Euclidian division: $a = b\times q + r$ and wrote $q = a\div b$, remains $r$.
No fraction were explicitely involved in primary school classes, but we reached decimal numbers, through the multiple and sub-multiple of unities: $1m = 100cm$ which we learned to be the same as $1cm =0.01 m$. Once those decimal numbers had been introduced, we could do decimal divisions, still with quotient and remainder, but where the quotient and remainder could have digits after a decimal point.
Fractions used to be presented several years after that with the set of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$. And I only found a proper definition of the set of real numbers ($\Bbb R$) after the baccalaureat.
